# Even, Odd, or Neither

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I would like someone to verify my solutions to the problems above?

9a. even 
9b. odd
10. neither

Comment: Correct. ${{{}}}$

Comment: Even functions are symmetrical with regards to the vertical axis Oy, and odd functions are symmetrical with regards to the point of origin, O.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, you are right.

#### Proper explanation

We say function $f$ is **even**, if for each $x \in D_1$, where $D_1$ is the domain of the function $f$, the following condition is satisfied:
$$
f(x) = f(-x).
$$

On the other hand, we say, that function $g$ is **odd**, if for each $x \in D_2$, where $D_2$ is the domain of the function $g$, the following condition is satisfied:
$$
- g(x) = g(-x)
$$
That's exactly the same as the fact, that $f$ is symmetric about the $y$-axis, resp. that $g$ is symmetric about the origin point in the coordinate system (simply the point $[0,0]$).
But usually I assume you won't be given the graph of the function, or you would not be able to draw the graph of the function precisely.

One of the easiest examples are:

**even** function $f(x) = \vert\, x\,\vert $, where $|\cdot|$ is absolute value.

**odd** function $g(x) = x $.

**Task.**
Of course not every function is even or odd, but there is one function which is both even and odd. Try to find it!

Comment: You are right... I was oversimplifying that in my answer.

Comment: It is often better to show the simpleness. But since it was already answered I could afford to give a deeper explanation.

I like to visualize mathematics a lot, but as you learn more it is harder to imagine everything and you won't avoid using strictly the definitions/theorems.